# Java Access Specifiers to access across packages without being public

Tags: java

I am building a java library which has different packages in it. Now the problem is, I want to access the java members (class, methods and fields) across the packages but those need not be exposed(from JAR file) to end level to client. For example

`Class B in Package B` should access the members of `Class A in Package A`

One possible scenario I found is declaring `protected` access specifier for the members of `Class A` and accessing those members in `Class B` by extending the `Class A` to `Class B` . **My question is is this the only way I can achieve it in java?**

What if I do not want to expose the Class A (as public) from JAR? In C# we use "internal" which will provide access within a CSharp library project but will not be exposed to end level from binaries(dll) or assembly files.

Comment: `new learner in Java.`  `I will deliver the JAR file at the end to the client`  - This scares me.

Comment: Wait til java 9 comes out and use modules!

Comment: @ScaryWombat : I have edited the question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: No, this is not supported in current Java versions, and extending a class is definitely not a good way to do that. Just document the class as internal, and use public.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing like this. You'll have to take a different approach. There are a *ton* of options, way too many to go over in a single answer, but off the top of my head just *some* basic ideas:

- This could be a red flag indicating poor package organization. Consider organizing your packages into more functional groups.
- This could be a red flag indicating some problematic design choices. Consider a more appropriate class and interface hierarchy.
- Consider adding interfaces that expose what you need to expose.
- Consider making said "internal" things public and safe to use externally.
- Etc.

But you *are* going to have to do a bit of reorganization here. If you start adding various hacks to get around it it may suffice for now but you'll likely regret it later on. Always best to try and get the job done as correctly as possible the first time around.